# C# Server - Socket not connecting and out of memory exception

Tags: c#, sockets, server

I am trying to implement a simple TCP server and I basically copied the example [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bb431f9(v=vs.110).aspx) sans a couple of lines and tried to make it work. I have an external client trying to connect already. 
This is my code:

```
IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
 IPEndPoint localEP = new IPEndPoint(ipHostInfo.AddressList[0], 4001);

 Socket listener = new Socket(localEP.Address.AddressFamily,
     SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

 try
 {
     listener.Bind(localEP);
     listener.Listen(1000);

    while (true)
     {

         listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCnxCallback), listener);
     }
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
   //Log here
 }
```

This is my callback:

```
private void AcceptCnxCallback(IAsyncResult iar)
{

    MensajeRecibido msj = new MensajeRecibido();

    Socket server = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
    msj.workSocket = server.EndAccept(iar);

}
```

And this is the information of one of the incoming packages:

```
TCP:[SynReTransmit #1727889]Flags=......S., SrcPort=57411, DstPort=4001, PayloadLen=0, Seq=673438964, Ack=0, Win=5840 ( Negotiating scale factor 0x4 ) = 5840
```

Source: 10.0.19.65 Destination: 10.0.19.59

I basically have two issues:

1. If I use the while loop I get an OutOfMemoryException
2. I never do manage to connect to the client

Any tips on either of the two problems? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I added it! It never even got ino the callback though. Thanks!

Comment: You look to be continuously calling BeginAccept. If you want to handle accept from within the while you probably want a blocking call rather than an async one.

Comment: The parts you missed out from the MSDN page look to be thread sync bits which would have prevented the infinite, non-blocking loop.

Comment: Would it bewise to do that if I was trying to accept multiple connections? I will try to figure out how to make the thread sync bits work, thank you!

Comment: Terrible article... Please take a look at this demo about how to build an asynchronous TCP server and client: https://github.com/vtortola/AynchronousTCPListener

Comment: I think the callback that they don't show on MSDN would signal to allDone to allow it to do another iteration of the loop to then accept the next connection. Unfortunately, the relevant parts don't look to be explained or shown. I would agree with @vtortola that it's a terrible article.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, that you use asynchronous calls all the time. There is no wait mechanism or similar, so generally you are just creating new asynchronous callbacks in an infinite loop.

For a basic TCP I would recommend to use the simple approach and use the synchronous methods.
Accept() is blocking, so the program flow will stop until there is an ingoing connection.

```
while (true)
{
    Socket s = listener.Accept();

    buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    s.Receive(buffer);
    //Do something
    s.Send(...);

}
```

Noe that this is just a basic example. If you want to keep your connection you might consider a new Thread for each accepted Socket, that continoues with receiving and sending data.

Answer (score -2):

First problem
You are using an infinite loop to call an async method.

try it like this:

```
listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCnxCallback), listener);

//add your code here (this part will be executed wile the listner is waiting for a connection.
while (true)
     {


         Thread.Sleep(100);

     }
```

and change the Callbackmethod to:

```
private void AcceptCnxCallback(IAsyncResult iar)
{

    MensajeRecibido msj = new MensajeRecibido();

    Socket server = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
    msj.workSocket = server.EndAccept(iar);

//call again the listener after you get a message
listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCnxCallback), listener);
}
```

Comment: A polling loop is not the solution to his infinite loop.

Comment: Surely the point of using the async methods is so that the thread doesn't get blocked, which is exactly what you're doing with Thread.Sleep.

Comment: @Ceisc you can replace the Thread.Sleep with your part of the code... I'll edit that part.

Comment: The point of the while loop is so that it starts waiting for the connection again after being told the the initial Accept is being handled. Breaking that out and having the BeginAccept called again from within the handler then negates the need for a while loop at all.

Comment: @usr i didn't say that it is an optimal solution, but it will fix his out of memory problem.

Comment: @Ceisc I've added while (true) Thread.Sleep(100) so that the main thread doesnt die. I dint added to refresh the listener. I'm refreshing the listener from within the handler.